# Create "div_by_ten" a boolean columns based on condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Consider a table consisting the marks of students in a mathematics test along with their unique student_id. Write a query to determine which students got the marks that is divisible by 10 and which students did not. Make sure that the output is ordered by student_id.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select *,
case
when mod(marks,10) = 0 then 'yes'
else 'no'
end as 'div_by_ten'
from marks
order by student_id;